# Data not inserting to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have my table setup as shown in the image below.

[image]

When I try and run the following code to insert the values into the database I get the error:

> FAIL: INSERT INTO `Betfairodds`
>   (`Horse`,`Back`,`Lay`,`TimeformTR`)VALUES( 'Intrepid','5.5', '5.9',
>   '0')

Would anyone be able to help, as I have tried to debug the code.

```
//loop through each individual card
    foreach ($getdropdown2 as $dropresults) {

 $horse = preg_replace('/\h*[^ a-zA-Z].*$/m', '', trim($dropresults->childNodes->item(8)->textContent));
 $back =  trim(GetBetween($dropresults->childNodes->item(18)->textContent, 'Back', '£'));
 $lay =  trim(GetBetween($dropresults->childNodes->item(20)->textContent, 'Lay', '£'));

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `Betfairodds` (`Horse`,`Back`,`Lay`,`TimeformTR`)VALUES( '$horse','$back', '$lay', '0')";
    $res = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        if (!$res) {

            echo PHP_EOL . "FAIL: $sql";
                 trigger_error(mysqli_error($db), E_USER_ERROR);

        }

}
```

Comment: this is fail because your second column is `int type`and you are sending `float value`.

Comment: use mysqli_real_escape_string against each value

Comment: @AK-Sonu I don't think '0' is a float value, do note that the columns are not inserted in the order they're in the table.

Comment: There should be something else also than just FAIL. What happens if you run the exact query manually into the database? Also, usually numbers shouldn't be sent as strings.

Comment: Running the exact query manually into the database works :S

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen - you can't send float values unless you quote them. The query looks fine. The issue might be that the db credentials are wrong so there's no connection available, hence query failing. The OP didn't post the rest of the error message.

Comment: @N.B. Umm, I see no error in inserting floats/decimals as actual floats/decimals. Not even MySQL seem to be that silly that it would force them to be sent as strings.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what is `mysqli_error` returning. E.g., append it to `echo PHP_EOL . "FAIL: $sql" . mysqli_error($db) ;` . Might it be a connection problem with `$db` var?

Comment: I said my comment based on this:-`FAIL: INSERT INTO Betfairodds (Horse,Back,Lay,TimeformTR)VALUES( 'Intrepid','5.5', '5.9', '0')`. according to table structure it always fails.

Comment: Fixed it - for some reason it was no displaying the CURRENT input but the past - the error was due to text being within the numbers. Thanks for everyone's comments in helping solve the issue

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen - well, if you don't believe me then enable query log, prepare the statement and issue a query with a float, check the log and see what MySQL does with it.

Comment: @N.B. I just inserted a bunch of floats into a table, MySQL 5.5, no problems. Just `INSERT INTO table VALUES (5.5)` so I guess my MySQL is broken?

Comment: @AK-Sonu Why would it? The columns are varchar, decimal, decimal, int and values are varchar, decimal, decimal, int.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen - I really don't know what happened in our communication channel, but you somehow mistook what I was saying. When you insert floats into MySQL using prepared statements, the values will be surrounded by quotes. Inserting floats via MySQL terminal works, I never claimed anything was broken or not working. What I referred to was your statement that numbers should not be sent as strings - however, that's completely irrelevant and using prepared statements will make PHP quote those numbers - no issues will arise. I would prefer not to continue this seeing the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the quotes `'` from 0 because it is defined as `int` in the schema and of-course added space right before `VALUES`  ..try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `Betfairodds` (`Horse`,`Back`,`Lay`,`TimeformTR`) VALUES( '$horse','$back', '$lay', 0)";
```

Answer (score -1):

Your statement is wrong. You should not put single quotes on the data fields. so it should be like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `Betfairodds` (Horse,Back,Lay,TimeformTR)VALUES( '$horse','$back', '$lay', '0')";
```